# Android Gradle Plugin 3.6 & 4.0 R8 not substituting src / main with src / test

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger

I run `Espresso` tests using `MockRetrofit` to test UI flows in the app. The `Espresso` tests rely on swapping the production `Dagger` `ApiModule` located in `src/main/java/com/my/app/ApiModule`

```
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun restApi(
        retrofit: Retrofit.Builder,
        @DefaultClientBuilder clientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder
    ): RestApi {
        val apiRetrofit = retrofit.client(clientBuilder.build()).build()
        return apiRetrofit.create<RestApi>(RestApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

with the fake `ApiModule` located in `src/androidTest/java/com/my/app/ApiModule`

```
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun restApi(
        retrofit: Retrofit.Builder,
        @DefaultClientBuilder clientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder
    ): RestApi {
        return MockApiModule.getApi(failureRate = FailureRate.NEVER, responseDelay = 500L)
    }
}
```

I just upgraded to AGP 3.6 (and then to 4.0). The tests are still passing when running `./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest`. But I also have a build configuration called `debugMinified`

```
buildTypes{
        ...

        debugMinified {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-testing.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    ...
}
```

which I use to run `Espresso` tests with an obfuscated apk to catch Pro-guard related Runtime errors.

Now when I run `./gradlew connectedDebugMinifiedAndroidTest`, my tests fail because AGP is not swapping the fake implementation in the `androidTest` src set, upon analysis of the apk. It's just using the real implementation in `main`. But again, this only happens for minified builds.

The above class `ApiModule` is one of 5 classes I swap out in this manner, when running UI tests. The other 4 have nothing to do with `Dagger` and are also not being swapped out, so I am relatively certain it's not just a `Dagger` issue.

This is currently blocking me from upgrading to AGP 4.0 so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I was able to resolve this issue simply by adding `@Keep` to all fake and real implementation class signatures

```
@Keep
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun restApi(
        retrofit: Retrofit.Builder,
        @DefaultClientBuilder clientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder
    ): RestApi {
        val apiRetrofit = retrofit.client(clientBuilder.build()).build()
        return apiRetrofit.create<RestApi>(RestApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

```
@Keep
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class])
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun restApi(
        retrofit: Retrofit.Builder,
        @DefaultClientBuilder clientBuilder: OkHttpClient.Builder
    ): RestApi {
        return MockApiModule.getApi(failureRate = FailureRate.NEVER, responseDelay = 500L)
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure why this works, or even why it's needed now. Just a lucky guess. Any further insight would be greatly appreciated.